# $A$ is a real orthogonal matrix, prove that $ (I+A)^{-1}(I-A)$ is skew-symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A$ is a real orthogonal matrix and $(I + A)$ is non-singular. Prove that $
(I+A)^{-1}(I-A)$ is a skew-symmetric matrix.

Attempt:

$[(I+A)^{-1}(I-A)]^t=(I-A)^t((I+A)^{-1})^t=(I-A)^t((I+A)^{t})^{-1}=(I-A^t)   ((I+A^t))^{-1}$

Please help me further.

Comment: You want to prove that this is $-\left(I+A\right)^{-1}\left(I-A\right)$. Multiply with appropriate things on the left and the right hand sides to "clear the denominators" (i.e., get rid of inverses).

Comment: @darijgrinberg please help me to do so in details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that
$$
       (I+A)^{-1}(I-A)=(I+A)^{-1}\{-(I+A)+2I\}=-I+2(I+A)^{-1}
$$
And $A^{t}=A^{-1}$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
       ((I+A)^{-1})^{t} & =(I+A^{t})^{-1} \\
                        & =(I+A^{-1})^{-1} \\
                        & =\{A^{-1}(I+A)\}^{-1} \\
                        & = (I+A)^{-1}A \\
                        & = (I+A)^{-1}\{(A+I)-I\} \\
                        & = I-(I+A)^{-1}.
\end{align}
Finally,
$$
   \{(I+A)^{-1}(I-A)\}^{t}=-I+2I-2(I+A)^{-1}=-(I+A)^{-1}(I+A).
$$

Answer (score 2):

$A$ is a real orthogonal matrix means $A^T=A^{-1}$:
$$
(I-A^T)(I+A^T)^{-1} = (I-A^{-1})(I+A^{-1})^{-1} =
A(I-A^{-1})A^{-1}(I+A^{-1})^{-1}=A(I-A^{-1})\bigl((I+A^{-1})A\bigr)^{-1}=(A-I)(A+I)^{-1} =-(I-A)(I+A)^{-1}
$$

**UPDATE**

Ok, let's show that
$$
(I-A^{-1}) = A(I-A^{-1})A^{-1}
$$
and
$$
(I+A)^{-1} (I-A) = (I-A)(I+A)^{-1}.
$$
It's obvious for me, but it's needed. It's simple for first:
$$
A(I-A^{-1})A^{-1} = (A-AA^{-1})A^{-1}=(A-I)A^{-1}=(AA^{-1}-A^{-1})=(I-A^{-1}).
$$
And it's not too hard for second:
$$
(I-A)(I+A)=(I+A)(I-A)
$$
(I think it's clear; if not, expand and substract), so
$$
(I+A)^{-1}(I-A)(I+A)=(I+A)^{-1}(I+A)(I-A) = (I-A)
$$
and
$$
(I+A)^{-1}(I-A)(I+A)(I+A)^{-1}=(I-A)(I+A)^{-1},
$$
or
$$
(I+A)^{-1}(I-A)=(I-A)(I+A)^{-1}.
$$
Note: we used that $I+A$ is non-singular (and have not use $(I-A)^{-1}$, for example).

Comment: this notation really hurts

Comment: @user251257, fractions hurts you?

Comment: fraction of matrices hurts, as matrix multiplication isn't commutative

Comment: @user251257, I completely disagree. We works with $A$, it's usual variable ($A$ is commutative with itself). Ok, let's write smth. like $(I-A^{-1})(I+A^{-1})^{-1} = A(I-A^{-1})(I+A^{-1})^{-1}A^{-1} = (A-AA^{-1})(A+AA^{-1})^{-1}$. Is it really better? It's unclear and leads to errors.

Comment: does $\frac A B$ mean $AB^{-1}$ or $B^{-1} A$? sorry, but no professional mathematician would ever write fraction for multiplication with the inverse in context of arbitrary matrices.

Comment: @user251257, with two matrix — of course. And you answered why. Ok, special for you I'll edit. I want to be like "professional mathematician".

Comment: .@MichaelGaluza The last expression of your new answer does not prove that $
(I+A)^{-1}(I-A)$ is skew-symm. Some more adjustment is needed. Please check and suggest.

Comment: @user1942348, look better

Comment: @MichaelGaluza $−(I−A)(I+A)^{−1}=\cdots=  -(I+A)^{−1}(I−A) $ this proof is now required. Is it not? (As I want to prove $[(I+A)^{−1}(I−A)]^t= -(I+A)^{−1}(I−A) $ )

Comment: @user1942348, oh, I see. $A$ commutes with itself. Do you want to prove  that $(I-A)(I+A)^{-1} = (I+A)^{-1}(I-A)$ separately?

Comment: @MichaelGaluza Yes, It is now essential. is it not?

Comment: @user1942348, we used commutativity yet. Look: $(I-A^{-1})(I+A^{-1})^{-1} =A(I-A^{-1})A^{-1}(I+A^{-1})^{-1}$. Why it's clear and last step is unclear?

Comment: @MichaelGaluza Yes, both have some ambiguity. I supposed that $I−A^{−1}$ can be written as $A(I−A^{−1})A^{−1}$ for the 1st case.

Comment: @user1942348, i'll edit post

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\bigl((I+A)^{-1}(I-A)\bigr)^t
&=(I-A^t)(I+A^t)^{-1}\\[4px]
&=(I-A^{-1})(I+A^{-1})^{-1}\\[4px]
&=(I-A^{-1})\bigl((A+I)A^{-1}\bigr)^{-1}\\[4px]
&=(I-A^{-1})A(A+I)^{-1}\\[4px]
&=(A-I)(A+I)^{-1}\\[4px]
&=-(I-A)(A+I)^{-1}
\end{align}
Now we're *almost* done: let's compare what we get upon multiplying on the left by $I+A$ the given matrix and its transpose in simplified form as obtained above:
\begin{align}
&(I+A)(I+A)^{-1}(I-A) &&-(I+A)(I-A)(A+I)^{-1}\\[4px]
&(I-A) &&-(I-A)(I+A)(A+I)^{-1}\\[4px]
&(I-A) &&-(I-A)
\end{align}
so the two matrices are indeed the negative of one another.

Just note that $(I-A)(I+A)=I-A^2=(I-A)(I+A)$.

Comment: cool, it's much shorter

Comment: @egreg $\bigl((I+A)^{-1}(I-A)\bigr)^t=(I+A^t)^{-1}(I-A^t)$ is this true?

Comment: @user1942348 No, let me fix it!

Comment: @egreg LHS is with the transpose. Your transpose is missing upon multiplying on the left by $I+A$.

Comment: @user1942348 In the final part I multiply the given matrix with the one I got after simplifying its transpose.