# Prove that A is orthogonal if $(I+A)^{-1} (I-A)$ is skew symmetric

Tags: matrices

$A$ is a real square matrix, $I$ is the identity matrix, and the matrix  $(I+A)^{-1} (I-A)$ is skew symmetric. Prove that $A$ is orthogonal.

Comment: What are your ideas on the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: @heptagon $A=I$ is not a counterexample.

Comment: @Gianluca Thanks, I am wrong. I am deleting my comment.

Comment: This is classical and known under the name Cayley Transform (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_transform) chapter "Matrix Map".

Comment: see similar (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1358375) ( http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1014064) etc.

Answer (score 2):

Since $(I+A)^{-1} (I-A)$ is skew symmetric, you get $$(I+A)^{-1} (I-A)=-\left(I+A^\top\right)^{-1} \left(I-A^\top\right),$$ which implies $$(I-A)(I+A)^{-1}=-\left(I+A^\top\right)^{-1} \left(I-A^\top\right),$$ or $$\left(I+A^\top\right)(I-A)=-\left(I-A^\top\right)(I+A),$$ which implies $2I=2A^\top A$.

(Note that I use the fact that $\left(B^\top\right)^{-1}=\left(B^{-1}\right)^\top$ to obtain the first display, and the fact that $(I-A)$ and $(I+A)^{-1}$ commute to obtain the second display. You gotta be able to prove these facts to complete the solution.)